# Windows Azure Blob Storage Data Migration

Tags: backup, amazon-web-services, azure, data-recovery, cloud-storage

I would like to back up the files I currently have in Azure Blob Storage and move them elsewhere. The problem is that pulling them one by one would take me several weeks, even within the same datacenter (not to mention the transaction costs).

Amazon seems to have the ability to move data around using physical media and ship the hard drives on demand: http://aws.amazon.com/importexport/

Does Microsoft offer similar services?

Is there a better way to migrate the data off Windows Azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know Microsoft doesn't offer any service like this yet.

Comment: It seems like it does now: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/storage/import-export-service-for-blob-storage/

Comment: Yep, just was announced in October or November.

Answer (score 1):

You could ship a hard drive to Amazon, and then use the [StartCopyFromBlob](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/06/12/introducing-asynchronous-cross-account-copy-blob.aspx) method to import from S3 to Windows Azure.

There is a usable code example [here](http://gauravmantri.com/2012/06/15/how-to-copy-a-bucket-from-amazon-s3-to-windows-azure-blob-storage-using-copy-blob/).

Comment: What I need is the reverse of what you are suggesting.

Comment: @DreamSonic: Sorry, my bad, it's late here. Maybe you could use it anyway? Upload from Azure to S3 and then export to drives?

Comment: The question is how do I efficiently upload from Azure to S3? As I said, it's going to take weeks and cost a fortune.